# How to set a tag to MenuItem?

Tags: android, menuitem

I am building a popup menu in android and I need to store some IDs in each menu item.
The IDs are String therefore it would be nice if I could set an array of String to the MenuItem.

The problem is that MenuItem does not have setTag method.

How else can I attach some data to it?

EDIT: 
Geobits mentioned about getActionView();

Unfortunately it returns null.

However, is it save to do the following?

```
 View view = new View(getActivity());
 view.setTag(tag);
 menuItem.setActionView(view);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each `MenuItem` has an associated `View` called an ActionView. If you're using a custom ActionView, you can fetch it using [`MenuItem.getActionView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getActionView%28%29), and set/retrieve the tag on it.

For instance, to set a tag:

```
public void setMenuItemTag(MenuItem item, Object tag)
{
    View actionView = item.getActionView();
    actionView.setTag(tag);
}
```

**Edit**

If you're not using a custom ActionView, you can use a HashMap to store tags. Use the MenuItem as the key.

```
public void setMenuItemTag(MenuItem item, Object tag)
{
    myMap.put(item, tag);
}

// returns null if tag has not been set(or was set to null)
public Object getMenuItemTag(MenuItem item, Object tag)
{
    return myMap.get(item);
}
```

Comment: getActionView returns null.

Comment: Ah. Well, in that case you can set up a `HashMap<MenuItem, Object>`. to store them in.

Comment: Is it better to use a `HashMap` or to do as I added to my post?

Comment: I've never tried it the way you edited, but I'm assuming that would change the looks/behaviour of your menuitem. Using a hashmap is fine, and is simple enough.

Comment: Ok. Good answer. I will just wait for a while maybe somebody else will add something.

Comment: on the onCreateContextMenu when you create the MenuItem you have to set the MenuItem.setActionView(yourView)  then only you can call MenuItem.getActionView() otherwise it will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky way to set tags when not using custom views.
The idea is pretty simple, after the Actual View is created, we try to find it by its text and icon

```
private void addButtonToMenu(Toolbar toolbar, Menu menu, String title, Drawable icon, String testId) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(title);
    if (icon != null){
        menuItem.setIcon(icon);
    }
    setTestId(toolbar, title, icon, testId);
}

private void setTestId(Toolbar toolbar, String title, Drawable icon, String testId) {
    UiUtils.runOnPreDrawOnce(toolbar, () -> {
        ActionMenuView buttonsLayout = ViewUtils.findChildByClass(toolbar, ActionMenuView.class);
        List<TextView> buttons = ViewUtils.findChildrenByClass(buttonsLayout, TextView.class);
        for (TextView view : buttons) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && title.equals(view.getText())) {
                view.setTag(testId);
            } else if (icon != null && ArraryUtils.containes(view.getCompoundDrawables(), icon)) {
                view.setTag(testId);
            }
        }
    });
}

// Helper functions

public class UiUtils {

    public static void runOnPreDrawOnce(final View view, final Runnable task) {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                task.run();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

public class ArrayUtils {
    public static boolean contains(Object[] array, Object item) {
        if (isNullOrEmpty(array)) return false;
        for (Object o : array) {
            if (o == item) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isNullOrEmpty(Object[] array) {
        return array == null || array.length == 0;
    }
}

public class ViewUtils {
    @Nullable
    public static <T> T findChildByClass(ViewGroup root, Class clazz) {
        for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = root.getChildAt(i);
            if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(view.getClass())) {
                return (T) view;
            }

            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                view = findChildByClass((ViewGroup) view, clazz);
                if (view != null && clazz.isAssignableFrom(view.getClass())) {
                    return (T) view;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> findChildrenByClass(ViewGroup root, Class clazz) {
        List<T> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = root.getChildAt(i);
            if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(view.getClass())) {
                ret.add((T) view);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```